# How do I install the manpage from node.js' source tarball?

Tags: command-line, install-from-source, manpage

I have downloaded `node.js` tarball from [its website](http://nodejs.org/), and now I would like install the manpage that comes with it so that I can view it by typing:

```
 man nodejs
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the reason for installing Node.JS from source? If you have a valid reason, that's fine, but it makes things like this more complicated than needed in some cases where you only need a more recent version than in Ubuntu. And have you run the `make doc` command as suggested in the README.md ?

Comment: You said there are manpages that come with the tarball, but I don't see any in the file.

Comment: @Ken Have a closer look. it's in `doc/node.1`.

Comment: Here's the general question: [How do I manually install a man page?](http://askubuntu.com/q/244809/2355)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `man nodejs`, but `man 1 node`. **And it will be there by default.**

It will be installed for you with the regular installation method (e.g. `sudo make install`) as the `tools/install.py` called from the `Makefile` will take care of it:

```
if 'freebsd' in sys.platform or 'openbsd' in sys.platform:
  action(['doc/node.1'], 'man/man1/')
else:
  action(['doc/node.1'], 'share/man/man1/')
```

In other words, it installs `node.1` for you in `/usr/share/man/man1/`.

---

To read the manpage directly from the source, you can do:

```
man /path/to/nodejssource/doc/node.1
```

Comment: I see I misunderstood the `man 1 node` syntax. I voted to delete my answer.

Comment: @user117123 No need to delete your answer. It provides a great way for viewing documentation anyway. :)

Comment: Ok, I undeleted, but clarified. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the man page, Node sets up its own help server.

```
npm help <term>
```

or to get started:

```
npm help npm
```

The documentation is also online at: [Node.js API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/)

Comment: thanks. I just saw your first comment and edited my answer.

Comment: The `node.1` is the exact file I want to link to `man` so that it will see it when I type `man node`

Comment: okay :) yeah, other documentation methods like `npm help` provide a lot more, but the `node` command also features a manpage, just for the convenience.