# How do I manually install a man page file?

Tags: command-line, manpage

How do I install a man page file system-wide?

For example, if I have a man page file `examplecommand.1`, how do I install it so that I can just type `man examplecommand` to view it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

1. First, find out which section your man page belongs to. If its a command, it probably belongs to section `1`. You can read the [manpage for the `man` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/man.1) to see a description of the different sections and their corresponding numbers.
2. Copy your man page to `/usr/local/share/man/man1/` (change `1` to your section number if need be). You can also install it to `/usr/share/man/man1/`, but it's best practice to use the `/usr/local/` directory for files that are installed without using the APT package manager. You can also optionally symlink over the file instead of copying it if you want:

   ```bash
   # First, ensure your local man page directory exists for your section of
   # interest (section 1 in this case, so the `man1` dir)
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1

   # Option 1: **copy** over the man page to section 1
   sudo cp examplecommand.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/

   # Option 2: **symlink** over the man page to section 1. 
   # NB: This cmd assumes you are already cd'ed into the dir in
   # which "examplecommand.1" is found, prior to running this cmd.
   sudo ln -si "$PWD/examplecommand.1" /usr/local/share/man/man1/
   ```
3. Run the `mandb` command. This will update `man`'s internal database:

   ```bash
   sudo mandb
   ```
4. That's it! You should be able to view the man page by running:

   ```bash
   man 1 examplecommand
   ```

---

#### References:

- The [manpage for the `man` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/man.1)
- The [manpage for the `mandb` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mandb)
- The source code in `/usr/bin/dh_installman` if you can read Perl, installed with the `debhelper` package.

Comment: Is there an option or what is the recommended practice when you would like to avoid using `sudo`?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran See the answer below on how to set MANPATH, which allows you to put manual pages in spaces you can write to, e.g.  $HOME/lib/share/man or somewhere like that

Comment: I think you could store the man pages under `/usr/local/man` as well as suggested in PATH to MANPATH mapping in `/etc/manpath.config` .

Answer (score 20):

**If you only need to install the man page *locally* :**

If `MANPATH` is unset, or includes an empty component (i.e. starts with `:`, ends with `:`, or contains `::`), then `<path>/share/man` will automatically be searched for man pages whenever `<path>/bin` is part of `PATH`, *for all values of `<path>`*.

This provides a very simple way to add man pages for locally installed software. There are some details in `man manpath` and `/etc/manpath.config`, but I don't see any mention of the generic mapping from `<path>/bin` to `<path>/share/man`.

Comment: I appended `MANPATH=<local path to the man pages>:$MANPATH` to your `${HOME}/.bashrc` (non-login sessions) or `${HOME}/.profile` (login sessions). In my case, I set up a local directory for man pages in `${HOME}/share/man/`, which mimicks the classical Linux filesystem. I created `${HOME}/share/man/man.1`, which then contains a symbolic link to the location to the file `examplecommand.1` wherever the program installer has put it (the configure 'prefix'). Launching `man examplecommand` finds the man pages in point. In this way the installation is local, though, not system-wide.

Comment: This was a very interesting comment, and it provides a path for people only needing to set their PATH (which they already expect) for local binaries.

However, I don't think the generic mapping `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/share/man` exists. When performing strace(1) on `man` with `MANPATH=:/nonexistingdir`, I see the following:

- `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/man`

This is on a Debain Buster system.

Answer (score 3):

For an application binary that was copied to `~/.local/bin`, copying its `.1` man file to **`~/.local/share/man/man1`** worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I had to create the latter directory. I can now access the man page using `man <app_name>`.

Comment: Do you have any official reference to this local man path? (small comment: not Ubuntu, but on Arch Linux this path means nothing by default, it is not automatically searched).

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @ntc2 above is the one people should be looking at. I wanted to add some extra commentary which didn't fit in the comments section:

The approach by @ntc2 provides a path for people only needing to set their PATH (which they already expect) for local binaries.

However, I don't think the generic mapping `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/share/man` exists for all paths in `$PATH`. It seems like this specific mapping is avoided when the `$PATH` in question is `$HOME/bin`. When performing strace(1) on `man` with `MANPATH=:/nonexistingdir`, I see the following lookups:

For any element in `$PATH` that's not `$HOME/bin`

- `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/man`
- `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/bin/man`
- `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/share/man`
- `<path>/bin` -> `<path>/bin/share/man`

For `$HOME/bin`

- `$HOME/bin` -> `$HOME/man`

I have no idea why it skips the others. This is on a Debian Buster system. It may be different on other systems.

For me, this means that the safest path to install man-pages is `<path>/man`, as it's guaranteed to be found if it's in the `$PATH`.