# How do I install a man page?

Tags: command-line, software-uninstall, manpage

After reading 
[How do I manually install a man page file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/244809/507051)
 (there is some ambiguity in this title) I did not get my answer.

How to install the related man pages for a certain command?

Take the command `ls` as an example, if the man page is not present, how can I install it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t need to install `man` pages manually, they are installed together with the command they describe. In the case of `ls` the program as well as the `man` page are part of the `coreutils` package, see [the package’s file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/coreutils/filelist) or the output of `dpkg -L coreutils`:

```
$ dpkg -L coreutils | grep [^a-z]ls
/bin/ls
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

If the `man` page wasn’t installed properly for any reason, just reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall PACKAGE
```

Though that is done automatically anytime a `man` page is added in the installation of a package, you can also update the database of `man` pages:

```
sudo mandb
```

If a command you seek help for is installed but has no `man` page, its help may be available elsewhere, see [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051) for alternatives.

If you want to install a `man` page *without* the corresponding package I recommend using `dman` as explaned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605348/507051).